# Add-AzADAppPermission Where to put what Guids? "Resource does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present."

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory

Within Azure, we set up our OATH2.0 credentials in AAD with three separate AppRegistrations.
I will be referring to these below.

1: Client : this is the main registration.
2: Read: This one holds the AppRole 'Read'
3: Write: This one holds the AppRole 'Write'

Here's some pictures to clearify:
3 Registrations
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lmJ4z.png)
AppRole inside Read:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7ICn.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LtPzP.png)

I am trying to automate adding these last two as APIpermissions to the first one with powershell.

I have found this command:
Add-AzADAppPermission and took a good look at the documentation here:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/add-azadapppermission?view=azps-9.3.0

However, Either I am missing something, or this maybe cannot be done with custom appregistrations?

I keep getting the message
"Resource does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present."

I have checked that I am on the correct Tenant, and I have sufficient rights.

There are four parameters to consider, some more clear to me then others.

- APIid: Which I assume, based on the documentation, should be Client.AppId
- ApplicationId:  Could be ObjectId/ ApplicationId from Read, but perhaps it's from it's corresponding ServicePrincipal (External Application)?, the documentation is not very clear on this one.
- ObjectId: Can replace ApplicationId, but I have the exact same question. the documentation does not specify anything other then "The unique identifier in Azure AD."
- PermissionId: The documentation says  but in the examples they use Guids. I have seen other examples with Strings like "User.Read", so I figure this could be my DisplayName from the appRole inside my Read / Write AppRegistrations.

I've looked for other examples beside the documentation, but so far I've found only examples regarding Built-in appRoles in MsGraph.

The fact that the message is twofold (either it is not there OR something is missing) does not help either.

Bottom line is, I can't figure out which Guid goes where.

I have tried numerous combinations of parameters and AAD Guids, be it ObjectIds and AppIds from both AppRegistrations and their respective Service Principles.

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the same error as below:***

[image]

> **`Note`** that: By using **`Add-AzADAppPermission`**, one can add the API permissions to the Application, but it is not possible to add
> custom roles as API permissions.

```
Add-AzADAppPermission -ObjectId ObjectID -ApiId APIIdofthepermissions -PermissionId GUIDofAPIPermission
```

I am trying to add **`Group.Read.All`** Microsoft Graph API permission like below:

```
Add-AzADAppPermission -ObjectId ObjectID -ApiId 00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000 -PermissionId 5f8c59db-677d-491f-a6b8-5f174b11ec1d
```

[image] [image]

Comment: Thanks Imran for your reply. So you're saying custom roles cannot be added like this. Can you share where did you get that Note from?

Comment: AFAIK, there is no documentation for the same